# php.ini config issue - testing file upload on 3 different servers

Tags: file-upload, lamp, php

hope someone can help as I'm not sure what's going on here - I have a live site where I want to allow file uploads of over 2MB. I have set the standard config options in php.ini as follows (running phpinfo() shows these settings fine):

```
upload_max_filesize 25M 25M
post_max_size   25M 25M
max_input_time  60  60
memory_limit    32M 32M
```

I also have the same config on a mirror server, where uploads of >2MB also don't work. Both of these servers are CentOS running php 5.1.6, with safe mode on. If I try out the settings above on a local LAMP set up on my laptop, the uploads work fine. So does anyone know if the problem could be a restriction of safe mode or if there are any other settings I need to configure?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Did you restart apache after modify configuration?

Comment: Hi, yes - I restarted apache, then checked phpinfo() to make sure the changes had taken effect, then tried the upload

Comment: Ensure that Apache's LimitRequestBody directive is not set.

Comment: Is there anything in $_FILES? `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: can you upload files smaller than 2MB? If not, take a look at your form and make sure it gets transferred by post, with an enctype="multipart/form-data" ..good luck ;-)

Comment: @timdev - that sounds like it could well be it if i can track down the setting, had a look in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf but nothing there, will dig around. @maraspin, yeah anything up to 2MB uploads fine, so don't think there's anything wrong with the server side script processing it, plus the same script allows me to upload >2MB on my laptop, the problem is just on these redhat servers with safemode on

Comment: @franko75 check the main httpd.conf file (and any others that get included) as well.

Comment: like @maraspin said, are files smaller than 2MB working? You might check the folder permissions on the destination directory. Also, it's possible the form itself is limiting the file size.

Comment: Are you trying to call move_uploaded_file anywhere in your script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this input in a [Drupal forum](http://drupal.org/node/109994#comment-743265) might help.

Did you apply the enctype in your form defenistion?

```
     <form id="putFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="...." method="post">
```